# Recording through an M-Audio Fasttrack Pro into Ardour with Qjackctl - No Input Signal?

Tags: ubuntu-studio, jack, external-soundcard, ardour

Update: linuxaudio states that the M-Audio Fast Track Pro can only work at 16 bit due to USB 1.1. http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/hw/m-audio_fast_track_pro

What does that mean to get it up and running? Compiling a custom kernel or just some audio settings?

---

Update: I've found some very different results regarding Fasttrack Pro in forums with older releases. Some state that the hardware is just incompatible e. g. here https://superuser.com/questions/308367/how-do-i-configure-my-m-audio-fast-track-pro-in-ubuntu and others state the got it to work without explaining how. On Debian, it works after patching the kernel e. g. here http://joegiampaoli.blogspot.de/2011/06/m-audio-fast-track-pro-for-debian-linux.html

I've contacted Avid Support (which now holds the brand M-Audio) but doubt they can help.

---

Trying to record my guitar through an M-Audio Fastrack Pro into Ardour. Qjackctl is running but I can't get an input signal. How can I fix this?

BTW: Guitar is plugged in, turned up and cable is working. I'm experiencing the same problem with a mic so that's not the cause.

[image: Qjackctl and Ardour are running]

[image: M-Audio Fasttrack Pro]

Let me know if more details are needed.

System Details:

```
64-bit ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Memory 7.6 GiB
Processor Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz × 4
Graphics Intel® Ironlake Desktop
600 GB HD (Boot from 120GB SSD)
Note that this is an Ubuntu Studio Setup
```